# Froala: Is there a way on image insert only to upload the image into the server but not into the editor?

Tags: angularjs, froala

I want the user to use the upload image button to upload the image in the server and then use the Image Manager to access the image whenever need it.
Currently, I use this

```
events: {   
          //This prevent the default image insert in the editor
          'froalaEditor.image.uploaded': function (e, editor, response) {
           $('#froala-editor').froalaEditor('commands.undo');
           $(".fr-image-resizer.fr-active").css("display", "none");
           $('#froala-editor').froalaEditor('imageManager.show');
           }   
}
```

This uploads the image into the server and after that undo the inserted image in the editor. And then opens the image manager where the image will be seen.
The problem is that the editor still contains the image edit buttons popup (imageEditButtons) and you have to click in the editor to unfocus this popup to 
Is there a better way for this customization?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#edit').froalaEditor()
  .on('froalaEditor.image.beforeUpload', function (e, editor, files) {
    if (files.length) {
      // Upload files to the server here.

      // When the file is uploaded insert it by using the image.insert method.
    }

    editor.popups.hideAll();

    // Stop default upload chain.
    return false;
  })
```